# ContentResolver AndroidX IllegalArgumentException Cannot provide null context for the database

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, androidx

I'm trying to fetch data from the content provider of application A.

The content provider is defined as follows in application A

```
    <provider
        android:name=".db.BDataProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.test.db.provider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:multiprocess="true"
        android:readPermission="android.permission.permRead" />
```

Now in application B i'm trying to read the data as follows

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            try {

                                String URL = "content://com.example.test.db.provider/user";
                                Uri uriObj = Uri.parse(URL);
                                String[] projection = {""};
                                String[] selectionArgs = {""};
                                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                                Cursor c = contentResolver.query(uriObj , projection, null, selectionArgs, "name");
                                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                                    String str = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                                    Log.d("", str);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

In the manifest of application B I've added

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.permRead" />
```

I get the following error at this line

```
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(uriObj , projection, null, selectionArgs, "name");
```

> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot provide null context for the database.**

```
2020-05-07 23:50:14.030 4294-4402/com.example.test D/ActivityThread: Loading provider com.example.test.db.provider: com.example.test.db.provider.BDataProvider
2020-05-07 23:51:36.017 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot provide null context for the database.
2020-05-07 23:51:36.019 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err:     at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:600)
2020-05-07 23:51:36.019 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err:     at com.example.test.db.BDatabase.getInstance(BDatabase.java:15)
2020-05-07 23:51:36.020 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err:     at com.example.test.db.BDataProvider.query(BDataProvider.java:42)
2020-05-07 23:51:36.021 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1057)
2020-05-07 23:51:36.021 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1149)
2020-05-07 23:51:36.022 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:241)
2020-05-07 23:51:36.023 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:757)
2020-05-07 23:51:36.024 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:706)
2020-05-07 23:51:36.025 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:664)
2020-05-07 23:51:36.025 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err:     at com.example.test.ui.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:313)
2020-05-07 23:51:36.027 4294-4402/com.example.test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Now comes the weird part, **the above code works in the project which is appcompatv7 based but gives be the above error in the new project created with androidX** dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question the listed code works in pre-androidX projects.

I was able to get a fix/workaround.

In application A, the Database class which extends RoomDatabase
I was using context.getApplicationContext()

```
public static synchronized BDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (dbInstance == null) {
            dbInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), BDatabase .class, DBConstants.DATABASE_NAME).build();
        }
        return dbInstance;
    }
}
```

replacing it to plain **context** fixes the issue.
Yes, context.getApplicationContext() didnt make sense in the first place.

```
dbInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, BDatabase .class, DBConstants.DATABASE_NAME).build();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55743967/3518278